# Golang UDP and TCP beside each other

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

is it possible to use TCP and UDP with each other in a single script? I need some of my packages to send and receive with TCP and some of them with UDP

```
func main() {

//
// ─── TCP ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//

// Listen for incoming connections.
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost"+":"+"3000")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}

// Close the listener when the application closes.
defer l.Close()
fmt.Println("Listening on " + "localhost" + ":" + "3000")
for {
    // Listen for an incoming connection.
    conn, err := l.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
    go gotcp.HandleRequest(conn)
    //go handler(conn)
}

//
// ─── UDP ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//

// then we should check which struct is empty and fill them

/* Lets prepare a address at any address at port 10001*/
ServerAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":3000")
goudp.CheckError(err)

/* Now listen at selected port */
ServerConn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", ServerAddr)
goudp.CheckError(err)
defer ServerConn.Close()

buf := make([]byte, 1024)

for {
    n, addr, err := ServerConn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
    //fmt.Println("Received ", string(buf[0:n]), " from ", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }

    // *** broadcasting
    //start := time.Now()
    if v, ok := goudp.RRoom()[djr]; ok {
        //fmt.Println("get room name ", v)
        go goudp.BroadCast(string(buf[0:n]), djr, ServerConn, v)
        //delete(R, "x")
        //go sendResponse(ServerConn, v.UserAddr1)
    }
    //elapsed := time.Since(start)
    //log.Printf("Binomial took %s", elapsed)
}

}
```

**EDIT:**
By passing tcp part or udp part in a function and call it like go tcpServer() we can use Both UDP and TCP with each other

Comment: You are engaged in one infinite loop that accepts TCP connections, and you are expecting it to magically exit and fall into your second infinite loop that handles incoming UDP. It won't work. Unclear why you think it should.

Comment: Typically binding two protocols into one port is not feasible in networking.

Comment: `I want to use UDP and TCP with each other.` no way. TCP does not communicate with UDP.

Comment: OK , IF I knew it, I wouldn't ask it. I use both TCP and UDP in node.js but in golang I'm new

Comment: @jeevatkm DNS is a rather prominent counter-example. TCP and UDP ports occupy distinct namespaces. There is no problem binding the same port to both protocols.

Comment: we can use the same port for UDP and TCP.UDP and TCP port are different in server side

Comment: @EJP yes you’re right about DNS. Let me give it try. Thanks

Comment: @jeevatkm DNS is merely a counterexample to your claim. What I'm right about is TCP and UDP ports occupying different namespaces.

Comment: As pointed by @EJP, UDP related code is unreachable due to infinite loop. The simplest solution will be: move the TCP related code from `main` function to a new function (say `serveTCP`) then in `main` function, before UDP related codes,  use goroutine to start serving TCP i.e. `go serveTCP()`.

Comment: @putu thank you so much it's work

Answer (score 1):

As noted by putu you need some concurrency to get it working properly.

NodeJS works with callbacks by default, which means that once you pass a function as a parameter to a function it will release the main loop to the next instruction. This is why NodeJS apps have the `object.method(function(){})` pattern. To achieve something similar to this in Go, you need to wrap the TCP and UDP portion of the program in a separate goroutine with a infinite loop each.

For a simple proof the concept, do something like this:

```
...
go func(){
  // paste your tcp code here 
}()
...
go func(){
  // paste your udp code here
}()
```

That "go" instruction says to the compiler that a portion of code should run concurrently. In a real-world project, you will put that portion of code in a proper function and just call it by name from your main function:

```
...
go serveTCP();
go serve UDP();
...
```

More about concurrency in go here => https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1